# Windows installer keeps reinstalling application after deleting file

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, windows-installer, c#, setup

I'm having a strange kind of problem with windows 10. I've created a Visual Studio Setup Project for an app. Installation runs fine, everything is good, I can start the app, use it ,close it, reopen it, everything works normally.

Now I'm deleting a DLL I installed as part of my app. I double click the desktop shortcut and... the setup starts again trying to repair or reinstall the whole setup.

Is that behavior expected?

Comment: You wrote the app. You tell us. To be frank.

Comment: There is no custom code in the installer project and on other OS's like windows 7 or 8.1 this does not happen (as far as I know), so this behavior must be specific for windows 10 install routines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found an answer. Its not win 10 but the shortcut created by the setup project
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f5fa6d83-9d7e-440c-a47e-3c64c9e6e269/problem-with-shortcuts-crated-by-installer-produced-by-visual-studio-2008-sp1-setup-project?forum=winformssetup